# 2nd div of row of inline divs starting on next line instead of behind previous div when previous div text overflows

Tags: html, css

What is the way of preventing a following inline div from displaying on a new line when the text inside a preceeding div overflows.

As you can see, for the first post the main content wraps onto a second row, and so the link following it is shown on a new line (which is incorrect).

But for 3rd post, the main title is short enough to only be on a single line, and there the link is correctly displayed following the title.

How can I prevent the first case where the link is shown on a new line?

Comment: add your html code like jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline;`, not `display: inline-block;` for both elements (you'll probably need a wrapper `div` then). Inline-blocks will have the full width of the container, if their content is at least one line long.

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first {
  display: inline-block;
}

.second {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first"><strong>inline-block</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. </div>
  <div class="first" style="color : green;">Here another element.</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="second"><strong>inline</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. </div>
  <div class="second" style="color : green;">Here another element.</div>
</div>
```